# Date display in a drupal view

Tags: date, drupal, view

I would like to display a list of dates in a view, but the problem is that the dates are recorded in SQL format.

I would like to convert this date to my local date format, I'd have to be able to change the field data output format

How can I do this??

Thanks by advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this solution :

I made modification in the "hook_field_formatter_view()" of my date-time field module.